# C .exe "stopped working" error

Tags: c, runtime-error, exe

This C program compiles just fine, but when I run it, after it asks for the first input, I get a windows error saying "hw.exe has stopped working".

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    int valA, valB, valC;
    double result;


    printf("Enter the first side of the triangle.");
    scanf("%d", valA);

    printf("Enter the second side of the triangle.");
    scanf("%d", valB);

    valC = (valA * valA) + (valB * valB);

    result = sqrt(valC);

    printf("The square root of %d is: %f\n", valC, result);

    return 0;
}
```

I am EXTREMELY new to C, so I'm sure that I am missing something super simple. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Turn on your comiler warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `&` (address-of) operator when using `scanf`. For instance,

```
scanf("%d", valA);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%d", &valA);
```

This is because `scanf` expects the argument to be a *pointer* to the variable you're reading from input, not the variable itself. A pointer is the location of a variable in memory. `scanf` uses this information to change the value of the argument you provide.

Therefore, when you pass a value to `scanf`, it uses it as a pointer, regardless of what you actually passed as C is relatively type-unsafe. When you use an unitialized variable where `scanf` expects a pointer, `scanf` tries to write to a random location in memory, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: A follow up question: when I run it, it allows for both inputs to be entered (thanks to your help) but then the program finishes and closes before I have a chance to read the output. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Just add `getchar()` to the end of your code, just before the `return` statement. This will prevent the program from closing until you hit enter.

Comment: Thanks much! You have been a huge help to this total noob. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an address to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &valA);
```

You must pass the **address** of `valA`, and then `scanf` will write into the variable at that address. Your code passes the **value** of `valA`.

And likewise you make the same change for the other call to `scanf`.